# problem with table view grouped table view 

Tags: iphone, uitableview

tableview problem: i am using 3 uilable for displaying productname, some description and image. all data displayed but when scrolling the table the labels are filled with another text with the actual text.. how can we handle this?
Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }


UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 41, 41)];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    NSDictionary *aDict1   = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    aDict1 = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *prdStus = [aDict1 objectForKey:@"ProductStatus"];
    NSLog(@"product status is %@ ",prdStus);
    if ([prdStus isEqualToString:@"Orange"]) {
        [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"]];
    }
    if ([prdStus isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {
        [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]];
    }
    if ([prdStus isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
        [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"]];
    }

    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46, 0, 220, 12) ];
    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    label2.text = @"";
    if (indexPath.row <[tableData count]) {
        label2.text = [aDict1 objectForKey:@"ProductName"];
    }

    [cell addSubview:label2];


    [cell addSubview:imageview];
    label2.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46, 13, 220, 30) ];
    label3.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    label3.text = @"";
    label3.text = [aDict1 objectForKey:@"ProductDescription"];

    [cell addSubview:label3];


    return cell;

}
```

please tell me how to avoid this..

Grouped Table view.

Here is also i am facing same problem.
I  am using 4 section
1st and 3rd  sections  1 row each,
2nd sec 3 rows,
4th sec 5

when configure the text the first section label displayed on 4th and 3rd section data also displayed on 4th section.
Code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 

    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    cell.userInteractionEnabled =NO;

if (indexPath.section == 0) 

    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 2, 294, 40) ];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        NSDictionary *aDict1   = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        aDict1 = [detailsArray objectAtIndex:0];

        label.text=@"";
        label.text =[aDict1 objectForKey:@"ProductName"];
        label.numberOfLines = 2;
        label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        [cell addSubview:label];
        [label release];


    //  [cell addSubview:imgview1];
    //  [imgview1 release];

    }

    if (indexPath.section ==1 ) {

            if (indexPath.row == 0) 
        {
            imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(255,2 , 46, 46)];
            [cell addSubview:imgview];
            [imgview release];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Actual Halal Rating";

            NSDictionary *aDict1   = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
            aDict1 = [detailsArray objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *statStr=[[NSString alloc] init];
            statStr = [aDict1 objectForKey:@"ProductHalalStatus"];
            NSLog(@"status is %@",statStr);

            imgview1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(255,2 , 20, 20)];


            if ([statStr isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {

                [imgview1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"]];

            }
            if ([statStr isEqualToString:@"Orange"] ) {

                [imgview1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"]];

            }
            if ([statStr isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {


                [imgview1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]];

            }
            [cell addSubview:imgview1];
            [imgview1 release];

        } 
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Halal (Permisible)";
            [imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]];
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Masbooh (Doubtful)";
            [imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"]];
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Haram (Not Permisible)";
            [imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"]];
        }

    } 


    if (indexPath.section == 2) {


        NSDictionary *aDict2   = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        aDict2 = [detailsArray objectAtIndex:0];
     // NSArray *ingrArr =[aDict2 objectForKey:@"IngredientInfo1"]; 
        textview1 =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 2, 294, 96)];
        //textview1.text = ingrStr;
        textview1.editable =NO;
        [textview1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
        [cell addSubview:textview1];
        [textview1 release];

    }


    if (indexPath.section == 3) {


    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line, from you code ....

```
if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

and add the following line

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: checked the edited answer i forgot to add one more line of code